# SQL - Compare rows by id, date and amount

Tags: sql, compare, rows

I need to `SELECT` a row in which `issue_date = maturity_date` of another row with same `id`, and same amount_usd.

I tried with self join, but I do not get right result.

Here is a simplified version of my table:

```
ID       ISSUE_DATE                     MATURITY_DATE        AMOUNT_USD
1       2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     2015-12-01 00:00:00.000     5000
1       2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     2001-09-19 00:00:00.000     700
2       2014-04-09 00:00:00.000     2019-04-09 00:00:00.000     400
1       2015-12-01 00:00:00.000     2016-12-31 00:00:00.000     5000
5       2015-02-24 00:00:00.000     2015-02-24 00:00:00.000     8000
4       2012-11-29 00:00:00.000     2015-11-29 00:00:00.000     10000
3       2015-01-21 00:00:00.000     2018-01-21 00:00:00.000     17500
2       2015-02-02 00:00:00.000     2015-12-05 00:00:00.000     12000
1       2015-01-12 00:00:00.000     2018-01-12 00:00:00.000     18000
2       2015-12-05 00:00:00.000     2016-01-10 00:00:00.000     12000

Result should be:

ID      ISSUE_DATE                         MATURITY_DATE        AMOUNT_USD
1       2015-12-01 00:00:00.000     2016-12-31 00:00:00.000     5000
2       2015-12-05 00:00:00.000     2016-01-10 00:00:00.000     12000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0a02/1

```
select a.id, a.issue_date, a.maturity_date, a.amount_usd
from tbl a
inner join tbl b
    on a.id = b.id
    and a.maturity_date = b.issue_date

    -- added to prevent same maturity date and issue date
where a.maturity_date <> a.issue_date
```

Output:

```
| id |                 issue_date |              maturity_date | amount_usd |
|----|----------------------------|----------------------------|------------|
|  1 |  January, 01 2010 00:00:00 | December, 01 2015 00:00:00 |       5000 |
|  2 | February, 02 2015 00:00:00 | December, 05 2015 00:00:00 |      12000 |
```

Comment: Thanks man, this helps a lot, but I still have a problem. There is a lot of data in real table, and in some cases when I have in the same row issue_date =maturity_date it returns that row also. I have Edited ID 5 to show you what I mean, and it returns also row whit id 5, what I do not want to. Can you please help me with this also?

Comment: added this: `where a.maturity_date <> a.issue_date`